# Tag synonyms: [us] vs. [usa]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently, we have two tags attached to questions related to the United States of America:

[us](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) and [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)

We should definitely consolidate them into one tag, because they have exactly the same meaning.

Now the all-important question: Which one will it be? [us](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) or [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)?

Comment: related : http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4/263

Comment: Other SE sites like [Workplace.se] use [united-states], so you'd better add that as well

Comment: @JanDoggen Done: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically it is "usa", which I think makes it clearer anyway.  This also opens up "us" for the many other items that it could be used for in the future: http://www.acronymfinder.com/US.html